# efficient two stage sorting of time series (first sort data 1 hour from now , then sort data 1 day from now, including the data sorted before)

Tags: sorting, time-series, time-complexity

I am given a task to generating alert when some suspicious log message is detected. A suspicious score is calculated for all log messages.

The first thing I have to do is to alert the user the most suspicious log in the past hour. I can find a sort algorithm in textbook to do this. This is not a big problem

The first problem I have is, how not to redo this sorting every second while sending alerts to the user as soon as something suspicious. Well. when you get a new log, just compare it with the most suspicious log from the last sort result. If it is more suspicious, just put it on top. If not, throwing it away seems not a big problem.

I guess maintaining a top n list and only resort the top n list is the way to go.

The second problem is, how to efficient combine the accumulated sorting result to get something like the top 10 most suspicious log of the day.

Any suggestion welcomed. Thanks. I am most familiar with python but any programming language or pseudo code is fine.

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem very well. But the usual way to incrementally  maintain sorted information - with entries being added and removed dynamically - is with a search tree or - if you only ever need to remove the max or min element - a heap data structure. You can search for both these terms.  Both are efficient enough to maintain several 10's of millions or more of entries if updates are only happening once a second.

Comment: thanks. I can tell you understand what I try to do with a list that keeps updating. can you direct me to some resources? I know the standard sorting technique for a static list in text books. Resources on a list that would keep being updated seems a bit rare. thanks again